# How can I remove the horizontal lines at the positions indicated below?

Tags: tables, tabularray, longtblr

How can I remove the horizontal lines at the positions indicated below? It looks weird since the bottom row  at the end of the first table and top row at the beginning of the continued table should be enclosed by a single pair of horizontal lines. If you have a better suggestion, please feel free to share it.

And just to clarify, this is just a made-up example, so it would be great if the solution could work in a general sense and not just for this one particular scenario.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=5cm,width=7cm,height=4.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  halign = c,
  caption = {Long Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{
  colspec = {@{}XXXX@{}},
  hline{1,Z}={3pt},
  hline{3,5,7}={1pt},
}
  1 & A & B & C \\
  2 & A & B & C \\
  3 & A & B & C \\
  4 & A & B & C \\
  5 & A & B & C\\
  6 & A & B & C\\
  7 & A & B & C \\
  8 & A & B & C \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT (based on the given answer):**

I attempted to use a longer table, but it doesn't appear to be functioning correctly. Specifically, I want to include lines below row 10 and one similar to the line above row 11, as shown in the image, to combine every two rows into a group. However, this approach is not yielding the desired results.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=8.5cm, 
    paperheight=5.5cm, 
    width=7.5cm, 
    height=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{mytemplate}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
  \vskip 6pt 
  \hrule height 2pt width \tablewidth
  \vskip -6pt 
}

\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}{
  \vskip -2pt 
  \hrule height 2pt width \tablewidth
}

\NewTblrTheme{mytheme}{
  \SetTblrTemplate{firsthead}{mytemplate}
  \SetTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}
}

\begin{longtblr}[
  halign = c,
  caption = {Long Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
  theme = mytheme,
]{
  colspec = {@{}XXXX@{}},
  hline{3,5,7,9,11,13,15}={1pt},
}
  1 & A & B & C \\
  2 & A & B & C \\
  3 & A & B & C \\
  4 & A & B & C \\
  5 & A & B & C \\
  6 & A & B & C \\
  7 & A & B & C \\
  8 & A & B & C \\
  9 & A & B & C \\
  10 & A & B & C \\
  11 & A & B & C \\
  12 & A & B & C \\
  13 & A & B & C \\
  14 & A & B & C \\
  15 & A & B & C \\
  16 & A & B & C \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to create your custom template which adds the thick lines only to the head of the first part of the table and to the foot of the last part of the table. The following should match the output as if you used `hline{} = {2pt}` for the `firsthead` and `lastfoot`.

(Thanks to ScumCoder for their suggestion related to correct spacing as well as to adding the `note` and `remark` parts.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=8.5cm, 
    paperheight=5.5cm, 
    width=7.5cm, 
    height=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{mytemplate}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
  \vskip \InsertTblrText{headsep} 
  \hrule height 2pt width \tablewidth
  \vskip -\InsertTblrText{headsep} 
}

\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}{
  \vskip -\InsertTblrText{footsep}
  \hrule height 2pt width \tablewidth
  \vskip \InsertTblrText{footsep}   
  \UseTblrTemplate{note}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default} 
}

\NewTblrTheme{mytheme}{
  \SetTblrTemplate{firsthead}{mytemplate}
  \SetTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}
}

\begin{longtblr}[
  halign = c,
  caption = {Long Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
  theme = mytheme,
]{
  colspec = {@{}XXXX@{}},
  hline{3,5,7}={1pt},
}
  1 & A & B & C \\
  2 & A & B & C \\
  3 & A & B & C \\
  4 & A & B & C \\
  5 & A & B & C \\
  6 & A & B & C \\
  7 & A & B & C \\
  8 & A & B & C \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

However, it seems that `hline`s at page breaks are not typeset by default (See also this somewhat related [issue at GitHub](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/130)). So, this is probably only half a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried out the code you recommended, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick for a longer table. I just updated my original post with more details. Do you think there's any way to modify the code to make it work for the longer table too?

Comment: @emnha I think the package assumes that you want to repeat the thicker top rule and bottom rule on each table part. Therefore lines at page breaks are removed. I currently don't know a way how to solve this. But I remember similar questions about problems with lines at page breaks. Maybe you can [file an issue](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray) to the package author.

Comment: Is it possible to draw horizontal lines with a white color to hide it? I attempted to do so manually, but was unable to draw any horizontal lines.

Comment: @emnha The problem is (as far as I understand it) that the package suppresses the typesetting of `hlines` that sit at page breaks in general. Instead it places copies of the `hline` defined for the top of the very first row and the `hline` defined for the bottom of the very last row. So, I don't think that this approach would be possible. But I might be wrong ...

Comment: @emnha There is no a nice solution provided [over at GitHub](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/50#discussioncomment-5503739).

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much. I hope the author will update it to make it easier to use.

Comment: `\vskip` argument should be `\InsertTblrText{headsep}` in `\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}` and `\InsertTblrText{footsep}` in `\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}`.

Comment: Also `lastfoot` is where `note`s and `remark`s are rendered, so when we redefine this template, we should insert them by hand. I suggest something like this: `\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytheme}{
  \vskip -\InsertTblrText{footsep}
  \hrule width \tablewidth
  \vskip \InsertTblrText{footsep}
  \UseTblrTemplate{note}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}
}`

Comment: @ScumCoder Thanks! This actually solves my troubles concerning the right spacing and also makes the code more robust!