# tabularray: do NOT add a horizontal line after last line on each page in longtblr

Tags: tabularray, hline, longtblr

The title says it all.

This is the polar opposite of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334607/106612). Whereas lexxie there was dissatisfied with the default behavior of `longtable`, I need to *achieve* this very behavior with `tabularray`.

[image]

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, digging this problem sent me to a rabbit hole.

For starters, this question [was already asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681561). It just didn’t show up during my search because of its title.
The most important piece of information from that thread is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681561#comment1691298_681602):

> the package suppresses the typesetting of hlines that sit at page
> breaks in general. Instead it places copies of the hline defined for
> the top of the very first row and the hline defined for the bottom of
> the very last row. It bears emphasis that this behavior does not
> depend on rowhead/rowfoot; lines will be copied even if both are zero.

That’s a start; now I can remove `\hlines` from the very beginning and very end of my `longtblr` (in case New Interface™ is used – by replacing `hlines` with `hline{2-Y} = {solid}`), and instead place them manually where they are needed by shoehorning them into the `firsthead`/`firstfoot`/`middlehead`/`middlefoot`/`lasthead`/`lastfoot` captions. It’s a rather ugly crutch, but it works.

Going to github issues revealed that the above mentioned behavior is a source of pretty serious problems; e.g., if you use Z as a row specifier, you [address last rows on every page](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/318), instead of the last row of the table (as one would expect); or if you set up the first/last line to look special, [they will suddenly creep up](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/130) on page breaks.

[Here](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/50#discussioncomment-5503739) I found a patch to the `tabularray` source code that allows to fix the first issue of the quote above: that “the package suppresses the typesetting of hlines that sit at page breaks”. This means that now I can add either `first hlines` or `last hlines` option to the table preamble, depending on what I need, and the proper inter-row line will be rendered where it should be. In turn, this means that now I have to shoehorn topmost and bottommost lines of that table only into the `firsthead`/`lastfoot` captions, which is still ugly, but definitely less so.

The perfect solution would be to fix the *second* issue of the quote above: that `tabularray` “places copies of the hline defined for the top of the very first row and the hline defined for the bottom of the very last row”. Another patch – disabling this behavior, – would allow to get rid of caption crutches altogether.

The `tabularray` author [threatened](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/130#issuecomment-944325923) to include the needed options into the package. Fingers crossed.
I’ll keep this half-answer non-accepted until then.